# Remove matched Rows from two Datatable

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net, .net-datatable

Here I have two `DataTable`s:

- dtTotalDateRangeExcludeSundays
- dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks

Each has 10k+ values, and I need to delete matched rows.

```
foreach (DataRow rw in dtTotalDateRangeExcludeSundays.Select())
 {
    DateTime dateFromRange=Convert.ToDateTime(rw[0].ToString());
    string strPrnt = dateFromRange.ToShortDateString();
    foreach (DataRow row in dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks.Select())
    {
      DateTime getDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[0].ToString());
      string strchild = getDate.ToShortDateString();
       if (strPrnt == strchild)
       {
          rw.Delete();
        }
       }
 }
```

I want to know if any better alternative suggestion, because the `foreach` loop takes time when bulk data is there.  I am not good with Linq, so I want to know if any Linq tricks work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you load the data into your `DataTable` instances from database, it's better to issue a direct `DELETE FROM ...` query over database rather than iterate on a client.

As a side note - it is an awful practice to compare dates by comparing strings. If your table has a `DateTime` column it's much better to cast the value to `DateTime` and compare typed dates like that:

```
DateTime dateFromRange = ((DateTime)rw[0]).Date;
....

    DateTime getDate = ((DateTime)row[0]).Date;
    if (dateFromRange == getDate)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost:

- Don't `Select()`. It's useless.
  `foreach (var c in collection)` is equivalent to:
  `foreach (var c in collection.Select())`, which is also the same as:
  `foreach (var c in collection.Select(a => a).Select().Select().Select(b => b))`.
- Don't use column indexes. Column names are less error prone.
- Don't `ToString` a date to parse it immediately after in order to stringify it again. I imagine that this is what you do with the first row.
- Use uniform style. For example, putting spaces before and after `'='` in some places but not in others doesn't increase readability. [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) may help.
- Don't use Hungarian notation (you can read [the article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) among others to know why).
- Use meaningless names for variables. There is no need to use cryptic names like `prnt`: they don't help understanding the code, and making a longer, more explicit name is not something hard to do. The same comes from `rw` and `row`: in general, `rw` is an abbreviation for read/write; if you use it for "row", what does `row` mean in your code? `strchild` is a terrible name too.

Using suggestions below, this gives:

```
foreach (var allDaysRecord in this.totalDateRangeExcludeSundays)
{
    var allDaysRecordDay = ((DateTime)allDaysRecord["Date"]).Date;
    foreach (var absence in this.absentsLeavesHolidaysWorks)
    {
        var absenceDay = ((DateTime)absence["Date"]).Date;
        if (allDaysRecordDay == absenceDay)
        {
            allDaysRecord.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

You can, if you want, LINQify that:

```
foreach (var allDaysRecord in this.totalDateRangeExcludeSundays)
{
    var allDaysRecordDay = ((DateTime)allDaysRecord["Date"]).Date;
    var hasAbsence = this.absentsLeavesHolidaysWorks
        .Select(c => ((DateTime)c["Date"]).Date)
        .Contains(allDaysRecordDay);

    if (hasAbsence)
    {
        allDaysRecord.Delete();
    }
}
```

You can go further:

```
var matches = from allDaysRecord in this.totalDateRangeExcludeSundays
              let allDaysRecordDay = ((DateTime)allDaysRecord["Date"]).Date
              where this.absentsLeavesHolidaysWorks
                        .Select(c => ((DateTime)c["Date"]).Date)
                        .Contains(allDaysRecordDay)
              select allDaysRecord;

foreach (var m in matches.ToList())
{
    m.Delete();
}
```

The code is cleaner, but you won't gain in terms of performance. If performance matters in this case, why aren't you doing the same thing as a single SQL query?